# Moving databases from XAMPP to a standalone MySQL 8 server

Tags: php, mysql, database, service, phpmyadmin

before I used xampp to start mysql server but recently I installed mysql server 8 and I need to transfer old databases that are in data folder in xampp to data folder that is in mysql server 8 but when I did that I get error when I try to restart mysql service. Can somebody explain to me how should I go about this?

I tried to change all files that is inside of mySql server 8 Data folder but it doesn't work, I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xampp is based on mariadb and its version is relatively low, so there will be problems directly by copying the directory. It is recommended to export and import through mysqldump.In addition, it is necessary to ensure that they use different ports, otherwise there will be port conflicts and the database will not start.